# facebook php login CSRF

Tags: php, facebook, csrf

I am trying to build a facebook user login with php.  I am able to get user info but every login creates an error log on my server `CSRF state token does not match one provided.` after login success.

I have found many tutorials around google for creating a facebook login.  I have also found a few other posts for the same issue.  They seem to blame calling getLoginUrl() more than once, which I am not doing.  And since I am using the example that comes with the sdk, I am confused why it is broken out of the box.

```
<?php
    require 'facebook.php';

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => 'APP_ID',
        'secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
    ));

    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($user) {
        try {
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

            $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
            echo "<a href=" . $logoutUrl . ">Logout</a><br><br>";
            print_r($user_profile);

        }
        catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e);
            $user = null;
        }
    }
    else {
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
        echo "<a href=" . $loginUrl . ">Login</a>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Have you allowed your URL in the app settings on facebook developper site?

Comment: Yes I have.  Anywhere I could find to put a URL I have entered my domain.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook SDK code has a bug when checking against tokens twice in the same handler.

I edited the getCode function of `facebook.php` like this:

```
protected function getCode() {
    if (!isset($_REQUEST['code']) || !isset($_REQUEST['state']) || $this->state === null) {
      return false;
    }
    if ($this->state === $_REQUEST['state']) {
        // CSRF state has done its job, so clear it
        $this->state = null;
        $this->clearPersistentData('state');
        return $_REQUEST['code'];
    }
    self::errorLog('CSRF state token does not match one provided.');

    return false;
}
```

to be more clear and does not state invalid token if called twice.

To be clear the function can be called twice on the same url handler if eg:

`$facebook->getUser();` and then in the same handler `$facebook->getLogoutUrl()` then the `getCode()` is called twice thus resulting into and invalid error message